# Verify ownership of a website

Tags: security, ownership, file-ownership

I'm creating a website where people can sell and buy digital products like websites, domains, scripts etc. My question is how can I determine if the user who wants to sell his website is really the owner of the website and not just an administrator or a developer who has access to the files? If anybody can give my an answer on this and a reference of technology to use to verify the ownership would be really great. I'm using laravel 5.1 for this project.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Google webmaster tools makes you upload a file with a random filename, or add a meta tag with a random string. If your bot can fetch the file or the string from the remote server, it is proof that the user is legitimate.

Comment: You can't actually. If administrator has access to server they will be able to upload any file. You can verify whois and compare e-mail but if data in whois are hidden you won't be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply ask the "owner" of the website to upload a file which has been created by you with either a random string name or includes a random string, which can only be recognized by your system.

You could upload these random codes to a MySQLi Database for reference.